# AWK, SED to format txt as CSV when input file may change

Tags: csv, text, awk, sed

I have this input but it might be different (have more similar entries)

```
Total Devices : 2


DEV#:   0  DEVICE NAME: Disk1 Part0  TYPE: 2145       POLICY: OPTIMIZED
SERIAL: 60050768018E033EC0000000000011A8
============================================================================
Path#            Adapter/Hard Disk        State  Mode       Select     Errors
    0     Scsi Port0 Bus0/Disk1 Part0     OPEN   NORMAL          0          0
    1     Scsi Port0 Bus0/Disk1 Part0     OPEN   NORMAL   17288503          0
    2     Scsi Port2 Bus0/Disk1 Part0     OPEN   NORMAL          0          0
    3     Scsi Port2 Bus0/Disk1 Part0     OPEN   NORMAL   17312166          0

DEV#:   1  DEVICE NAME: Disk2 Part0  TYPE: 2145       POLICY: OPTIMIZED
SERIAL: 60050768018E033EC0000000000011A9
============================================================================
Path#            Adapter/Hard Disk        State  Mode       Select     Errors
    0     Scsi Port0 Bus0/Disk2 Part0     OPEN   NORMAL   10322705          0
    1     Scsi Port0 Bus0/Disk2 Part0     OPEN   NORMAL          0          0
    2     Scsi Port2 Bus0/Disk2 Part0     OPEN   NORMAL   10321466          0
    3     Scsi Port2 Bus0/Disk2 Part0     CLOSE  DEAD            0          0
```

I would like to have an output like this:

```
DEV#:   0  DEVICE NAME: Disk1 Part0  TYPE: 2145       POLICY: OPTIMIZED;SERIAL: 60050768018E033EC0000000000011A8;0;Scsi Port0 Bus0/Disk1 Part0;OPEN;NORMAL;0;0
DEV#:   0  DEVICE NAME: Disk1 Part0  TYPE: 2145       POLICY: OPTIMIZED;SERIAL: 60050768018E033EC0000000000011A8;1;Scsi Port0 Bus0/Disk1 Part0;OPEN;NORMAL;17288503;0
DEV#:   0  DEVICE NAME: Disk1 Part0  TYPE: 2145       POLICY: OPTIMIZED;SERIAL: 60050768018E033EC0000000000011A8;2;Scsi Port2 Bus0/Disk1 Part0;OPEN;NORMAL;0;0
DEV#:   0  DEVICE NAME: Disk1 Part0  TYPE: 2145       POLICY: OPTIMIZED;SERIAL: 60050768018E033EC0000000000011A8;3;Scsi Port2 Bus0/Disk1 Part0;OPEN;NORMAL;17312166;0
DEV#:   1  DEVICE NAME: Disk2 Part0  TYPE: 2145       POLICY: OPTIMIZED;SERIAL: 60050768018E033EC0000000000011A9;0;Scsi Port0 Bus0/Disk2 Part0;OPEN;NORMAL;10322705;0
DEV#:   1  DEVICE NAME: Disk2 Part0  TYPE: 2145       POLICY: OPTIMIZED;SERIAL: 60050768018E033EC0000000000011A9;1;Scsi Port0 Bus0/Disk2 Part0;OPEN;NORMAL;0;0
DEV#:   1  DEVICE NAME: Disk2 Part0  TYPE: 2145       POLICY: OPTIMIZED;SERIAL: 60050768018E033EC0000000000011A9;2;Scsi Port2 Bus0/Disk2 Part0;OPEN;NORMAL;10321466;0
DEV#:   1  DEVICE NAME: Disk2 Part0  TYPE: 2145       POLICY: OPTIMIZED;SERIAL: 60050768018E033EC0000000000011A9;3;Scsi Port2 Bus0/Disk2 Part0;CLOSE;DEAD;0;0
```

I tried this:

```
sed "/=/d;{:q;N;s/\n/;/g;t q};s/;;/;/g" input.txt
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That worked for me:

```
awk '$1=="DEV#:"{nr=$2; dn=$5; ty=$8; pol=$10} \
$1=="SERIAL:"{sn=$2} $1~/[0-9]/{printf "DEV#:\t%s  DEVICE NAME: %s %s  TYPE: \
%s\t\tPOLICY: %s;SERIAL: %s;%s;%s %s %s %s;%s;%s;%s;%s\n", nr, dn, $5, ty, pol, \
sn, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9}' file
```

**Explanation:**

- `$1=="DEV#:{...}`: if the first field is `DEV#:`,  set the variables `nr`, `dn`, `ty` and `pol`
- `$1=="SERIAL:{...}"`: if the first field is `SERIAL:`, set the variable `sn`
- `$1~/[0-9]`: if the first field is a digit...
- `{printf "..."}`: ...print the information in the desired format.

Answer (score 0):

This leaves you with the task of writing the formatter, remember that in `awk` a user defined function can access all the variables defined in the outer scope.

```
egrep -e ^DEV -e ^SERIAL -e '^ +[0-9]' datidisk | awk '
function process(output_lines) { for(l=1;l<output_lines+1;l++){....}}
/^D/ {if(output_lines){
         process(output_lines);
         output_lines = 0 ; }
      head1 = $0 ; next}
/^S/ {head2 = $0 ; next}
     {output_lines += 1 ; lines[output_lines] = $0}
END  {process(output_lines)}
```